# How to display an image in a fixed div to make a scrollable image panel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am making a photo gallery script that involves displaying an image in a fixed width/height box. Now I want that image to display in its complete size. I mean, if the box is `700x300` px, the image should not resize to `700x300` but should display at its own full resolution. Also if possible, can I somehow make it drag around in the box so that it can be viewed completely?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a draggable pane you need two elements, an outer div to act as a container, and an inner div to act as a 'canvas'.  The outer container needs to have its style set to `overflow: hidden`.

```
<div id="drag-container">
    <div id="drag-canvas"><img></div>
</div>
```

Next you need to make your inner canvas draggable.  On `mouseDown` on the inner, call a function that sets a variable `dragging = true`.  On `mouseUp` call a function that sets it to `false`.  You'll want to also store the mouse position on `mouseDown` and subtract the top and left position of the inner div so you can use that as an offset.

Then on `mouseMove` have the inner canvas' top and left position set based on the mouse position.  Don't forget to add the offset so that the inner canvas drags from the point which you grabbed it at, otherwise the top left corner of the div will snap to the mouse position.

There are also several libraries, like [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) that has a "draggable" method you can apply to a div directly, simplifying this process.  The real key is to have the outer container set with a hidden overflow.

Comment: although the comment did help, i am new at javascript and didnt understand how to implement the mouseDown and mouseMove functions. can you pls elaborate on this?